# AppConfig::File retrieving values

Tags: perl, configuration, app-config

I am trying to use [AppConfig::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AppConfig%3a%3aFile) for handling a config file. However, I am always getting an empty value from the object. The following is the code:

```
my $state = AppConfig::State->new( {
    CREATE=>1,
  } );
my $cfgfile = AppConfig::File->new($state);
$cfgfile->parse('sample.cfg');
my $temp = $cfgfile->{foo};
print "foo value: $temp\n";
```

This is in the sample.cfg:

```
## comment
foo = me
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to include the [ARGCOUNT](http://p3rl.org/AppConfig%3a%3aState#ARGCOUNT) setting in the definition of the variable. Not sure how to do it dynamically from the file.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use AppConfig ':argcount';
use AppConfig::File;

my $state = AppConfig::State->new( {
    CREATE=>1,
  } );
$state->define('foo', { ARGCOUNT => ARGCOUNT_ONE });
my $cfgfile = AppConfig::File->new($state);
$cfgfile->parse('sample.cfg');
print "state value: '", $state->foo(), "'\n";
```

Comment: I tried this way before but it shows error: `Can't locate object method "foo" via package "AppConfig::File" at testAppConfig.pl line 55.` Any other idea?

Comment: In [AppConfig::State](http://search.cpan.org/~abw/AppConfig-1.66/lib/AppConfig/State.pm) you have more ways to retrieve variables, such as `->get("foo")`. Perhaps you need to do `$state->foo()`? The variables might be saved in State, but parsed in File.

Comment: `print ref $state->foo()`. *Might* be an array of 1 in a scalar context. Or just `print $state->foo()`.

Comment: Nope.. still doesn't wory.. I have tried `print ref $state->foo();` but it prints nothing. Then for `print $state->foo();` it prints a `1`.

Comment: In http://search.cpan.org/~abw/AppConfig-1.66/lib/AppConfig/File.pm#CONFIGURATION_FILE_FORMAT is the explanation: `Variables that are simple flags and do not expect an argument (ARGCOUNT = ARGCOUNT_NONE) can be specified without any value. They will be set with the value 1, with any value explicitly specified (except "0" and "off") being ignored. `

Comment: hmhm... that's just talking about putting no value for a variable, then it will set the variable to `1`. But how can I get the value `me`? Very confused now.....

Comment: @Kenneth let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1562/discussion-between-tlp-and-kenneth)

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but I found this works if you don't want to predefine everything.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use AppConfig ':argcount';

my $config = AppConfig->new( {
    CREATE => 1,
    GLOBAL => { ARGCOUNT => ARGCOUNT_ONE },
  } );
$config->file('sample.cfg');

print $config->foo();
# or
print $config->get('foo');
```